# htaccess does not redirect primary URI

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two WordPress installation

```
example -> contains installation for example.com
|_ blog -> contains installation for example.com/blog
```

`blog` is a directory inside `example` which already has a WordPress installation. this works fine. I now wanted to redirect users visiting without www (example : http://example.com/blog/some-topic to http://www.example.com/blog/some-topic) hence i added following wild card rule .htaccess redirection rule inside of blog directory, find below content of .htaccess of blog directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

It redirects correctly for all URI which contains topic like

- example.com/blog/some-topic is redirected to www.example.com/blog/some-topic
- example.com/blog/new-topic is redirected to www.example.com/blog/new-topic

And so on... my issue is when i try redirecting just the example.com/blog it redirects me back to www.example.com, what am i missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your htaccess located in blog folder?

Comment: Yes, It is located in blog folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last rule with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/blog/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Working perfect, thank you, can you help explaining what happened ?

Comment: There was a slight typo in your orignal rule's destination. it was redirecting to / istead of /blog as $1 doesnt capture the directory.